# infer -- gradle build is not working

Tags: android, facebook-infer

I'm trying to use the Infer tool to analyze my app code. I followed [these steps](http://fbinfer.com/docs/hello-world.html#hello-world-android) and every time I'm trying to run `infer -- gradle build` I'm getting the below errors :

```
infer -- gradle build
Running and capturing gradle compilation...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/infer", line 183, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/infer", line 147, in main
    capture_exitcode = imported_module.gen_instance(args,cmd).capture()
     File     "/usr/local/Cellar/infer/0.8.1/libexec/infer/lib/python/inferlib/capture/gradle.py", line 87, in capture
cmds = self.get_infer_commands(util.get_build_output(self.build_cmd))
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/infer/0.8.1/libexec/infer/lib/python/inferlib/capture/util.py", line 25, in get_build_output
proc = subprocess.Popen(build_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
       File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea would be appreciated !!

Comment: it looks like you may be running infer--gradle rather than infer -- gradle (note the spaces around the --).

Comment: Thank you I tried but it didn't work :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Infer is already included in the new android studio 2.2 where you can run it directly from Analyze->Infer Nullity then specify the scope.

[image]